# scala java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following code is causing java.lang.NullPointerException.

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val dataFramePerson = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").schema(CustomSchema1).load("c:\\temp\\test.csv")
val dataFrameAddress = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").schema(CustomSchema2).load("c:\\temp\\test2.csv")

val personData = dataFramePerson.map(data => {
  val addressData = dataFrameAddress.filter(i => i.getAs("ID") == data.getAs("ID"));
  var address:Address = null;
  if (addressData != null) {
    val addressRow = addressData.first;
    address = addressRow.asInstanceOf[Address];
  }
  Person(data.getAs("Name"),data.getAs("Phone"),address)
})
```

I narrowed it down to the following line of that is causing the exception.

```
val addressData = dataFrameAddress.filter(i => i.getAs("ID") == data.getAs("ID"));
```

Can someone point out what the issue is?

Comment: culprit line should be `val dataFramePerson = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").optionval personData = dataFramePerson.map(data => {` . what is personData? you haven't defined if its a val or var and it should be on the next line i guess

Comment: Thanks for catching the messy code. That was just cut and paste issue. It was not the real issue. The code is now fixed for the question.

Comment: when you have used map on `dataFramePerson` then only the values of that object or constants can be used inside that map function. you cannot use `dataFrameAddress` or any other objects inside that map function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a big structural flaw, that is, you can only refer to dataframes from the code that executes in the driver, but not in the code that is run by the executors. Your code contains a reference to another dataframe from within a map, that is executed in executors. See this link [Can I use Spark DataFrame inside regular Spark map operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619570/can-i-use-spark-dataframe-inside-regular-spark-map-operation)

```
val personData = dataFramePerson.map(data => { // WITHIN A MAP
  val addressData = dataFrameAddress.filter(i => // <--- REFERRING TO OTHER DATAFRAME WITHIN A MAP
          i.getAs("ID") == data.getAs("ID"));  
  var address:Address = null;
  if (addressData != null) {
```

What you want to do instead is a left outer join, then do further processing.

```
dataFramePerson.join(dataFrameAddress, Seq("ID"), "left_outer")
```

Note also than when using `getAs` you want to specify the type, like `getAs[String]("ID")`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can be said is that either `dataFrameAddress`, or `i`, or `data` is `null`. Use your favorite debugging technique to know which one actually is e.g., debugger, print statements or logs.

Note that if you see the `filter` call in the stacktrace of your `NullPointerException`, it would mean that only `i`, or `data` could be `null`. On the other hand, if you don't see the `filter` call, it would rather mean that it is `dataFrameAddress` that is `null`.